# Initializer list for vector of objects

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, initializer-list

I have the following sample code. Is it possible to initialize a list of objects without specifying the "Test" in the vector of objects, or is this the best way? Thanks.

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(const std::initializer_list<int> list) : m_(list) {

    }

private:
    std::vector<int> m_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<Test> v = { Test({1, 2, 3}), Test({1, 2, 4}) };


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works:

```
std::vector<Test> v = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}};
```

But I'm not sure if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

The following are all valid methods to initialize a `vector<Test>`.

```
 std::vector<Test> v1 = { Test({1, 2, 3}), Test({1, 2, 4}) };
 std::vector<Test> v2{Test({1, 2, 3}), Test({1, 2, 4}) };

 std::vector<Test> v3 = { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}};
 std::vector<Test> v4{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}};
```